# Extended POSIX utilities using command find on Mac OS X?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, terminal, find

I try to do this command on my Mac OS X 10.9 Terminal:

```
find / -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex "(.*A.*a.*.*)|(.*a.*A.*.*)" -exec tail -n 3 '{}' \;
```

But the Bash v 3.2 response is:

```
find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator
```

I have made a deeply search on Terminal manpages:

```
man find

man regex
```

etc...

But I find nothing. Does the Mac OS X Bash v3.2 should to be updated? It seems that the option "-regextype" is not included in the "find".

How can I fix it?

p.s.
The command works perfectly on Ubuntu Linux 14.

Comment: So your question is whether it should be updated? :p That's not much of a question, and it's certainly not a programming question. Mac utilites lack some power found in their linux counterparts. There might be a way to get the extended/newer versions. The `-regex` flag already exists on Mac though.

Comment: No, the question about updating is ironic. :P My question is "how can I fix it?", in other words: there is a way to do the same command? I found yet a solution:

`find / -type f -regex ".*A.*a.*.*" or -regex ".*a.*A.*.*" -exec tail -n 3 '{}' \;`

And it works.

Comment: If you like software features beyond bash 3.2 you should probably decide to use a different OS? A GNU/Linux system could fit your requirements.

Comment: @hek2mgl your view of the capabilites of a mac system is slightly off

Comment: @kitsune: It's a feature of find and not of your old bash.

Comment: @keyser No it is isn't and bash 3.2 says all. Of course you can install GNU tools (as on Windows) but would you still say it is a "mac system" then? Mac OS is good for graphics and guys with too much money.

Comment: @hek2mgl You seem to be unaware of the fact that Mac is Unix. Comparing it to Windows in terms of terminal capabilites is ludicrous.

Comment: @keyser Please follow my answer history on SO and you'll realize that I'm *indeed* aware of this. (Please also check my answer here which makes the discussion somewhat obsolete)

Comment: @keyser Note that GNU is not UNIX ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Your history tells me that you know Linux (quite well), but that's not really the subject here :p GNU is not Unix, but both your comments regarding Mac (Unix) are off. I'm sure you're well aware of their history and current similarities (Mac-Terminal-wise). I'm assuming you haven't used a Mac for an extended period of time (since it's just for graphics guys :p). I'm writing this from an Arch distro so I'm no fanboy, I just happen to know both systems in terms of command line utilities somewhat well. I've never lacked anything in a  Mac Terminal.

Comment: And OP, you found your answer after searching for regex stuff within the man page, right? If so, just remember to be patient :)

Comment: @keyser Yes, I never used it. :) But I've answered a lot of questions which were about the differences between commandline tools on GNU and UNIX (mostly mac I assume). I'm aware of the fact that what GNU tools are doing is not always standard and sometimes UNIX is "right", but developers should like that GNU stuff (and therefore support it, by using it)... (imo).. (I attach importance on the fact that I did not downvoted this post)

Comment: Using homebrew, you can install GNU findutils and bash 4.3 on OS X.  http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Mac OS X comes with BSD tools, but you can install GNU versions yourself.

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest answer to your question is that on OS X you need to use the `-E` option instead of `-regextype posix-extended`

ie:

> find / -type f **-regextype posix-extended** -regex "(.*A.*a.*.*)|(.*a.*A.*.*)" -exec tail -n 3 '{}' \;

becomes:

> find **-E** / -type f -regex "(.*A.*a.*.*)|(.*a.*A.*.*)" -exec tail -n 3 '{}' \;

and aside from the `-exec tail` command that complains, the above works on my 10.10 installation.

This is actually covered by the first entry of the man page:

```
 The options are as follows:

 -E      Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic
         regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic regex for that:

```
find / -type f -regex "\(.*A.*a.*.*\)\|\(.*a.*A.*.*\)" -exec tail -n 3 '{}' \;
```

Comment: Like as: `find / -type f -regex ".*A.*a.*.*" or -regex ".*a.*A.*.*" -exec tail -n 3 '{}' \;` Thank you very much.